# Обработка информации в разных потоках независимо друг от друга

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть программа. К примеру при её запуске она получает некую информацию, после чего попытается поделить её поровну на указанное количество потоков. Каждому из потоков будет предоставлен ровно такое же количество информации для обработки что и всем другим.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    while (true) {

        List<User> users = getUsers(); //здесь максимум будет size() == 1000

        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Users are empty! Sleep 5 minutes...");
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
            System.out.println("Wake up!");
            continue;
        }

        List<List<User>> partition = ListUtils.partition(users, 100); //делим большой лист по 100 объектов

        List<Callable<Void>> callables = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<User> list : partition) {
            callables.add(() -> {
                work(list);
                return null;
            });
        }

        executor.invokeAll(callables);

    }
```

Т.е. информация обрабатывается 10ю потоками, НО... проблем заключается в том, что если один или несколько потоков завершили обработку информации, то они ждут пока остальные потоки сделают тоже самое -> `executor.invokeAll(callables);`, для того, чтобы получить новую порцию информации.

Вопрос в том, как правильно реализовать архитектору приложения для того, чтобы потоки работали так:
Поток завершил обработку - взял новую порцию информацию и ему не нужно ждать, пока все потоки завершат выполнение, другими словами потоки должны работать независимо друг от друга.

**UPD**. Почитал про *work stealing*. Пригляделся один из вариантов, сделал по его принципу. Что можете сказать? Как можно улучшить?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<User> users = API.loadUsers();
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invoke(new WorkTask(users));
    }

}

public final class WorkTask extends RecursiveAction {

    private final static int SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD = 25;
    private List<User> users;

    private WorkTask(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (this.users.size() <= SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD) {
            work();
        } else {
            int middle = this.users.size() / 2;
            List<User> newList = this.users.subList(middle, this.users.size());
            this.users = this.users.subList(0, middle);
            WorkTask task = new WorkTask(newList);
            task.fork();
            this.compute();
        }
    }

    private void work() {
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Это называется [work stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing). Можно реализовать как самостоятельно, например с помощью очереди, так и использовать решение "из коробки" - [fork/join framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я изучил принцип work stealing, сделал набросок, можете глянуть(вопрос обновлён)?